# Add ' * ' after string based on salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I have columns `Name` and `Sal` and I should create a string of `Name` and then put * based on salary (1000$ = * ), so for example

```
Clark | 5000$
Smith | 4000$
```

would look like:

```
EMPLOYEES_AND_THEIR_SALARIES
-------------------------------
Clark  *****
Smith  ****
```

Thanks for responding.

Comment: Can you show at least how you tried to solve your problem? This site is not about *write code for me*

Comment: Seems like number of `*` depends on the first digit of your Salary value. Like for 5000 its 5 and for 4000 its 4. Let me know if this is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rpad()` for this purpose.  Assuming the salary is stored as a number:

```
select name, rpad('*', salary / 1000, '*')
```

Comment: I guess this is not what OP wants. @Bob jarvis has shown it correct. OP wants if `5000$` then `*****`. I mean total length of `5000$` , that many `*`. Your solution is not correct.

Comment: @XING . . . And what is the difference between `TRUNC(salary / 1000)` and `salary / 1000` that will be passed as an integer to the function?  The two answers are equivalent.

Comment: Yes..bt even that answer now seems not correct of you look at the OP question. I asked for clarification.

Comment: @XING . . . The question is pretty clear to me:  "put * based on salary (1000$ = * )".  The OP wants one `*` per thousand.

Answer (score 1):

The following will provide the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT NAME, RPAD('*', TRUNC(SAL / 1000), '*')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As far i could understand, the below one should suffice your need.

```
select first_name ||'  '|| rpad('**',length(salary),'*') Name   from employee;
See Demo;
```

Table Data

```
SQL> select first_name , salary ,length(salary) from employee;

FIRST_NAME               SALARY LENGTH(SALARY)
-------------------- ---------- --------------
Dan                        1234              4
Helen                      3213              4
Akiko                      9000              4
Jackie                    40000              5
XING                      40000              5
```

Output: here `*` are as per the length of Salary.

```
  SQL> select first_name ||'  '|| rpad('**',length(salary),'*') Name
      from employee    ;

    NAME
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dan  ****
    Helen  ****
    Akiko  ****
    Jackie  *****
    XING  *****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE replicate_example (
Salary INT
)
INSERT INTO dbo.replicate_example
    ( Salary )
VALUES  ( 3000 ), (5000)

SELECT CAST(Salary AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + REPLICATE('*',Salary / 1000) FROM     dbo.replicate_example
```

Comment: This is not oracle. Question is tagged for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT ename, 
       LPAD(' ', TRUNC(( sal * 12 ) / 1000), '*')sal 
FROM   test_j2
```

[Test results](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_ET0JTNHMFDT7RCYI4IOC0757E.html)